# Freezes after a period of time on an intel i945

Tags: 10.10, intel-graphics, freeze

Recently installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my intel PC. After i log in and desktop appears it freezes after sometime. Mouse does not work and neither the keyboard. I have this same problem with Ubuntu 10.04. But i used 9.04 for over an year. There was no such problem with 9.04. Currently I have a dual-boot system setup with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 (which is not working). 
The specifications of my system are :

Intel 945G series chipset motherboard.

core2Duo

2 GB DDR2 RAM

Comment: I don't know if this could be a valid cause of a freeze but I had same issue with 10.04, 10.10 and even 11.04, and root cause was Google Chrome with Sync enabled, ya that's weird but the problem got solved in all the three versions when I removed syncing from Chrome.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this chipset.

Try turning visual effects off.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsIntel